# Splitting a dynamic array into multiple arrays

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, arraylist

I'm trying to split a dynamic array of unknown length into multiple parts and return all parts as an array list, each array in the list of given length. I've searched around on here for a solution but have only come across solutions for fixed length arrays. I've had a bash at it and come up with this:

```
private static ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();

public static ArrayList<String[]> split(String input[], int splitSize){
    int place = 0;
    int place2 = splitSize;

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length/splitSize; i++){

        String[] part = new String[splitSize];
        System.arraycopy(input, place, part, place2, splitSize);

        place = place + splitSize;
        place2 = place2 + splitSize;

        System.arraycopy(input, place, part, place2, splitSize);
        list.add(part);

    }
    return list;
}
```

I keep getting out of bounds errors, but I'm not sure where it's wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciate, thanks!

EDIT::
For those googling and looking for a quick answer, this method splits your standard arrays and adds leftovers onto the end:

```
public static String[][] split(String[] input, int splitSize) {
    int numOfSplits = (int)Math.ceil((double)input.length / splitSize);
    String[][] output = new String[numOfSplits][];
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfSplits; ++i) {
        int start = i * splitSize;
        int length = Math.min(input.length - start, splitSize);
        String[] part = new String[length];
        System.arraycopy(input, start, part, 0, length);
        output[i] = part;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: List is an array list initialized in the class, `private static ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();`

Comment: Post minimal code which is unambiguous to solve the problem you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] leftover = null;
System.arraycopy(input, place, leftover, place2, splitSize);
```

How can you copy something in a `null` array?

See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)),

```
public static void arraycopy(Object src,
         int srcPos,
         Object dest,
         int destPos,
         int length)
```

Throws:

```
NullPointerException - if either src or dest is null.
```

**EDIT** as OP changed the code:

Your problem is here,

```
int place2 = splitSize;
```

You are assigning `place2` with `splitSize` and then creating a new arrays of string like,

```
String[] part = new String[splitSize];
```

Then, you are trying to copy `input` into `part` in index `splitSize`. Remember, arrays are zero indexed.

Say, `splitSize = 2`. Then `part` will be array of length  `2` of strings indexed `0` and  `1`.

Then in line `System.arraycopy(input, place, part, place2, splitSize);` you are trying to copy something in `part`'s `2` index. Hence `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurred.

May be this help you:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SplitArray {
    private static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static ArrayList<String> split(String input, int splitSize) {
        int place = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length() / splitSize; i++) {
            String part = input.substring(place, place + splitSize);

            list.add(part);

            place += splitSize;
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "aabbcc";
        split(input, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I came up with another method using 2D arrays from your advice, I'll leave it in my original question for those who find the same problem and come looking!